# UTC date insertion in Oracle DB using JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, utc

I am developing a RESTful web service using JPA on Servicemix.

I have to store date timestamp in UTC format in Oracle DB. I am able to convert date in UTC using various solutions on console but date is stored in local time zone only.

I used below two solutions that print date correctly but insert local time not UTC in Oracle database.

1-

```
public static Date utcDate()
{
    Date dt = new Date();
    Date utcDate=null;
    //Try to format your date with the Z or z timezone flags
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy 
HH:mm:ss a Z");
    String strUTCDate = dateFormatter.format(dt);
    System.out.println("UTC Sting - "+strUTCDate);
    try{
        utcDate=dateFormatter.parse(strUTCDate);
    }catch(ParseException ex){System.out.println("Exception while parsing String date to Date Object.");}
    System.out.println("UTC Date Obj - "+utcDate);
    System.out.println("System Date - "+dt);
return utcDate;
}
```

2-

```
Timestamp.from(LocalDateTime.now().toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) )
```

I am using below entity to store date in hibernate

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="LAST_WORKED_ON_DTIME")
private Date LastWorkedOnDtime;
 public Date getLastWorkedOnDtime() {
    return LastWorkedOnDtime;
}
public void setLastWorkedOnDtime(Date lastWorkedOnDtime) {
    LastWorkedOnDtime = lastWorkedOnDtime;
}
```

Comment: What datatype you have in database? And which version of JDBC drivers you use?

Comment: Database Datatype is TIMESTAMP and Hibernate 4.3

Comment: The classes `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Timestamp` are long outdated and poorly designed. I recommend that you generally use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. A modern Hibernate can directly store those to your database (sorry, I don’t know Hibernate versions, so don’t know whether 4.3 does, please check yourself).

Comment: If you're stuck with the old libraries, then maybe saving it as `java.util.Calendar` rather than `java.util.Date` could work, since `Calendar` stores timezone information that will be passed on to the JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks for this update...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this manually if you are using hibernate version since 5.2

You can use the `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` configuration property, as explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/).

Basically, you can now force the UTC time zone for all `TIMESTAMP` and `TIME` columns using the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is resolved. Below changes made in existing code.

1- Change in Model (Entity Class) - take field as TIMESTAMP type,

```
@Column(name="LAST_WORKED_ON_DTIME")
private Timestamp LastWorkedOnDtime;

public Timestamp getLastWorkedOnDtime() {
    return LastWorkedOnDtime;
}
public void setLastWorkedOnDtime(Timestamp lastWorkedOnDtime) {
    LastWorkedOnDtime = lastWorkedOnDtime;
}
```

2- Set field Value before persist.

```
sdheaders.setLastWorkedOnDtime(Timestamp.from(LocalDateTime.now().toInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ));
```